# VisualVM thread dump not matched with heap dump?

Tags: java, jvm, visualvm, jstack

I written a dead lock example code and then use VisualVM analyze it, I find that the object caused dead lock, its address is different between thread dump and heap dump.

The exmaple code is:

```
package com.example.chapter4;

/**
 * @author Cnfn
 * @date 2017/11/05
 */
public class ThreadDeadlock {
    static class SyncAddRunnable implements Runnable {
        int a, b;

        public SyncAddRunnable(int a, int b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (Integer.valueOf(a)) {
                synchronized (Integer.valueOf(b)) {
                    System.out.println(a + b);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            new Thread(new SyncAddRunnable(1, 2)).start();
            new Thread(new SyncAddRunnable(2, 1)).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Then run the example code, `Integer.valueOf(1)` and `Integer.valueOf(2)` will cause dead lock. But those address are different between thread dump and heap dump.

The thread dump:

[image: threaddump]

The heap dump:

[image: heapdump]

But `jstack` command result matchs heap dump:

[image: jstack]

So, why VisualVM's thread dump not match heap dump? Why `jstack` result match VisualVM's heap dump?

Or, something wrong with me?

Thank you~~~

PS: I execute program again, and upload application snapshot, heap dump, thread dump and jstack log to [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WxuoPakJKXa3nEjiM7xfuS7MlRc8hTJW?usp=sharing)

Comment: Where are you getting the first thread dump from? Are you sure this is the same process?

Comment: All of them get by one process in VisualVM. I execute program again, and upload application snapshot, heap dump, thread dump and jstack log to [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WxuoPakJKXa3nEjiM7xfuS7MlRc8hTJW?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object ID in the dump is the address of this object in Java Heap.

GC can move objects across the heap. The fact that the address has changed means there was a GC between the moment when you ran jstack and when you made a thread dump with VisualVM.

Comment: But these Integers should be probably located in Constant pool, right? Why GC might need to move objects in PermGen/Metaspace? There was nothing like unloading classes in this example I guess...

Comment: @user3714601 All Java objects live in Java Heap. Even when constant pool contains an object (`java.lang.String` or `java.lang.Class`, but not `java.lang.Integer`), it still refers to an object in Java Heap.

Comment: You are right! Yesterday, I firstly dump threads, then dump heap, finally execute jstack command. Now I firstly dump heap and then threads, all things are right. It's like that a GC when dump heap. But I cannot find anything about it in the internet. Do you know what happen when dump heap?

Comment: @apangin, but Integers in this example must be pooled, right? Am I wrong that such pool of Integers resides in PermGen/Metaspace? I beleive it was so, at least in earlier versions, but can't find a proof yet...

Comment: For sure, I mean the common pool of small Integers, from -128 to 127.

Comment: @user3714601 They are not in Metaspace. `java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache` class contains a regular Java array of type `Integer[]`.

Comment: @Cnfn Yes. By default, Visual VM takes a heap dump of only live objects - and this causes GC before the dump.